# jQuery slide up with CSS border causes strange 'jump'

Tags: jquery, css, animation, border

I have a load of `li`s which I slide up using jQuery and the `animate()` function. Using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` gives the same effect which I will now describe: the `li`s slide up just fine, but when their heights are zero the borders (top and bottom, 1px) remain, then snap out of existence all at once. I'm wondering... is there a way in jQuery to get the borders to not 'snap' away, but smoothly slide up/down like the rest of the `li` or `div` or whatever.

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
.animate({
    height: 'toggle',
    margin: 'toggle',
    padding: 'toggle',
    opacity: 'toggle'
});
```

I tried using the `border` CSS property with `'toggle'`. It works fine for sliding up, but when sliding back down, the borders snap back into existence at the end of the easing animation.

Comment: It would be easier if people could see it in action with something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: +1 for the virual window polish comment

Comment: @Archonix - edited :-) Also, thanks very much for the link - I didn't know stuff like that existed! Awesome.
@John Hartsock - thanks :-P

Comment: You forgot the .com (or whatever) in your link.

Comment: @Grillz - Apologies. I am using a local server and copied the link from that :-P Fixed now.

Comment: @Archonix This just gets more embarrassing by the second :-P It's fixed FOR SURE now. Sorry :-)

Comment: No Problem - but before I look at the code there is something funky going on in Safari (not in FF though). Screenshot here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/526220/Screen%20shot%202010-11-11%20at%202.32.51%20PM.png just FYI :)

Comment: Funky and a half! I'll fix that when I can :-) As for the original problem, I've pretty much fixed it thanks to John Strickler

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem with the border animation on my end. (FireFox 3.6) is this happening specifically in IE, Safari or Chrome?

Comment: Awesome! I'll just take my off-topicness over here ---> :)

Comment: Lol :-) try again - Safari should show fine now. It turned out that I was closing the <script> tag like this: `<script/>`. I regex-replaced a load of stuff to reduce the amount of errors I get when validating.

Comment: @Archonix This is happening in FF 3.6.13pre. No worries though - I've managed to fix it :-)

Comment: Close, just one more line of errors on screen http://dl.dropbox.com/u/526220/Screen%20shot%202010-11-11%20at%202.41.24%20PM.png

Comment: Bah! Try again :-P Thanks for your time and help by the way :-)

Comment: No Problem. It's always nice to have a set of extra eyes (and extra browsers). I'm off now, but GL with the site.

Comment: Thanks :-) I had Safari going on Wine but never saw that error. Although, I haven't tested it on Safari in yonks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what you are talking about.  I've done this before and had the same issue.  The work around is to animate a containing div inside of the border div.  Its the same effect.

For example...

```
<!--- Flakey --->
<div class="border slideMe">
   Content here...
</div>

<!--- Correct --->
<div class="border">
   <div class="slideMe">
      Content here...
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this saves you some headache.

Comment: So you are saying the border CSS goes on the `class="border"` bit, and everything inside it is slid up? I'll give it a go - thanks.

Comment: Yes, put all the CSS in the div with the .border.  Put the content in the inner div.  It should work.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's still _slightly_ off, but it's a vast improvement on what I had before :-)