# Make element visible with an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently developing a plugin that enabled me to mimic the Office Ribbon interface for web applications.

Now, everything up now is functional, but I want to add some animation to it, just as in the original Ribbon.

For people who have Outlook 2013, you can see the behaviour what I mean:

When you click on item that has a dropdown (f.e. "New items") the dropdown comes fly in from the top.

Now, I have created a dropdown myself which become visible by clicking on the icon, but this is without animation (just display block).

Can someone provide me the code I need to make it fly in from the top?
You can find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/nf7Lr/

my menu is decorated with the following class:

```
<div class="menu" id="mnuCleanUp">
```

So, I want the menu to fly in from the top (just under the clicked button).

Kind regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the menu

```
$("#mnuCleanUp").slideDown("slow");
```

and to hide it back

```
$("#mnuCleanUp").slideUp("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks, the "SlideDown" function is what I need. However, I have a problem with the css when using the SlideDown() function. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/nf7Lr/2/ Would you be so kind to have a quick look?

Comment: looks ok to me, not clear with what css problem you see

Comment: I have it in both Chrome and Firefox (only ones I've tested). As the animation progresses, the position at the top is moved by 1 pixel and the left border is added at last when the animation is completed. Be sure to check in the latest version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/nf7Lr/2/ Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found my answer already here on the forum. Seems to be a known bug when using borders. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158335/jquery-slide-up-with-css-border-causes-strange-jump

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has built in method to have smooth appear/disappear

Have you check : http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

The easing attribute let you choose different effects : http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Ok, I've added the fadeIn option (see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Complexity/nf7Lr/1/) but it's just fading in the menu. I really want to fly it in from the top? Any advice on that one?